# ClickOnce Deployment of multiple EXEs and Config files

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I have a WPF solution (C# & VS 2012) that calls an external EXE. I've added a reference to the external EXE in the main (Dashboard) project.

The solution is getting packaged into the ClickOnce package and published. The issue I'm running into is that the CONFIG file for the external EXE is not getting picked up in the ClickOnce package.
When I open the Application Files window on the Publish tab in VS2012 it shows the external EXE.

But the configuration file for external EXE is not listed, even with the "Show All Files" checkbox selected.

So my question is:

Is there a way to either manually add a config file to the ClickOnce deploy package or somehow coerce it to see the config file?

This is my first ClickOnce deployment project so I'm struggling a little here and any assistance would be appreciated!

Thanks!

**UPDATE/SOLUTION FOUND:**
After much web surfing I found an fix for this issue. Here's the posting on MSDN that helped me [MSDN: ClickOnce and External config](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4b38d5f9-10d3-4436-a40d-9b19f3fa146c/clickonce-and-external-config-files?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4b38d5f9-10d3-4436-a40d-9b19f3fa146c/clickonce-and-external-config-files?forum=winformssetup). This at least solved the issue for me in the short term. As noted in the MSDN post it can cause issues down the road if the external config changes frequently.

Comment: I think there should only be one config file for your application.  All relevant configuration items in the external exe's config file should be copied in to your application's config file

Comment: If you need a screen shot, include the URL in your post and a moderator cam embed it.

Comment: @PatrickY -- The second EXE is completely separate, it can't "see" the main/calling app's config file. This setup is working just fine, re: the 2nd EXE and config file, on my machine. My issue is that I can't get it to be included in the deploy package.

Comment: If you solved you problem; add it as an answer, don't add it to the question. You can answer your own questions, in fact you can get upvoted and badges for answering your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE/SOLUTION FOUND: After much web surfing I found an fix for this issue. Here's the posting on MSDN that helped me [MSDN: ClickOnce and External config files](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4b38d5f9-10d3-4436-a40d-9b19f3fa146c/clickonce-and-external-config-files?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4b38d5f9-10d3-4436-a40d-9b19f3fa146c/clickonce-and-external-config-files?forum=winformssetup). This at least solved the issue for me in the short term. As noted in the MSDN post it can cause issues down the road if the external config changes frequently.

Comment: But... what was the solution?